# Проверка на определенные куки

Tags: php, cookie, mysql

Всем привет. Есть система опросов, там может быть несколько разных вопросов. Как сделать так, чтобы я мог голосовать в разных опросах по 1 разу? С помощью `setcookie`.

Как можно проверить, голосовал ли я в этом опросе уже или нет?

Comment: IP-адрес, обязательная регистрация, подтверждение по e-mail. Ибо печеньку и затереть могут.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!

Для реализации этой задачи не обязательно использовать `Cookie`, вы можете определять IP адрес голосующего и допустим версию ОС (иногда IP адрес один для целой компании) и путем `AJAX` запроса сохранять в БД. Таким образом вы сможете сделать уникальность голосования, а следовательно решить вашу задачу.

Если же вам все таки нужно решать ее именно через `Cookie`,  То важно будет учесть корректность даты истечения, а так же то, что `cookie` не будут видны системе до полной перезагрузки страницы. Таким образом вашу задачу нужно решать так:

1. нажали на голосование (оставили свой голос)
2. Отправляем `AJAX` запрос на сервер (собственно он заносит в БД + выставляет `Cookie`)
3. При успешном ответе `AJAX` запроса - отключаем кнопку голосования
4. При дальнейших перезагрузках страницы проверяем наличие `Cookie`

Подробно аналогичную задачу разбирают здесь - [Setting a cookie in an AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431906/setting-a-cookie-in-an-ajax-request)

Но от себя подчеркну - `Cookie` не самый лучший способ для решения данной задачи.

Удачи!

Comment: Здравствуйте. Саму систему я уже реализовал, все это сделал.

Единственное, что не очень понятно, если я записываю в куки вот так: setcookie("vote", $_POST['id'], time()+60*60*24*30);, то человек ведь не сможет ответить на остальные вопросы, например, в базе 3 вопроса, он отвечает на 1 из них, и больше не может голосовать..

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю то vote есть голос, а $_POST['id'] есть собственно оценка. Затруднение в том, что вы не знаете как получить за какой собственно вопрос этот голос. Если это так, то вы можете засунуть в Cookie массив значений. Выглядеть это будет так. 

$vote = array('vote' => $_POST['id'], 'questionID' => $_POST['quesID']); 
$stringAr = serialize($vote); 
setcookie("vote", $stringAr, time()+60 * 60 * 24 * 30);

Для получения затем значений из куки, сначала получите строку обчным образом И ПРЕМИНИТЕ ДЛЯ НЕЕ urlencode, а затем unserialize - это и будет ваш массив.

Comment: Во избежании минусов к моему совету сразу скажу, ЭТО НЕ ЕСТЬ САМЫЙ ЛУЧШИЙ СПОСОБ. Лучше, как мне кажеться, хранить в куке (раз уж вы ее используете), ID структуры БД, в которой в сою очередь храниться ID вопроса и  оценка пользователя.  Массив, класс и иная структура в сессии или куках есть ПЛОХО!

Comment: $_POST['id'] - это айди вопроса (AI из БД)

Comment: if($_COOKIE['vote'] == 2) будет верно же?

Comment: Тогда не понятна проблема вашего первого комментария. Создаете таблицу в которой храниться id вопроса (вторичный ключ), оценка, ip пользователя, ос или еще что то.  При заходе пользователя в голование проверяете по IP и ОС голосовал ли пользователь здесь и какой голос оставил. Собственно, задача cookie здесь вообще отпадает..

Comment: Да, if($_COOKIE['vote'] == 2) будет верно, однако вы завалите пользовательский браузер куками. А кроме того при очистки кук браузера все обнулится и можно будет накрутить ваше голосование как угодно. Почитайте комментарий выше

Comment: Мы имеете в виду, что если будет много разных вопросов, то в куках будет много лишней информации? А если будет 2-3 вопроса, ничего страшного?